# How to use hWnd in C#

Tags: c#

I've been trying to figure out how to use a dll, which can be directly used in C#.

Here's the function

```
Open( BSTR bstrDevice, BSTR bstrLogFile, DWORD hWnd, UINT uMsgType, UINT uMsg);
```

where hWnd is

```
hWnd
The windows handle of a window that will receive messages. No messages are sent if set to zero, and any calls that normally would generate messages are synchronous.
```

It can be totally ignored, but I certainly want to know how to use it in C#.

Any component, item or tool can be input to the function? What would happened if function returns anything? How do I get return values?

Comment: You know to use in c#, Where you are using it now??

Comment: [`myForm.Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hWnd` is the handle of the form that will receive windows messages related to the execution of your DLL function (`Open`). I do not know the details of this function, so I cannot tell you which kind of messages are going to be received by the form...

For passing a valid form handle to the function, you can simply pass `myForm.Handle` to the DLL, where `myForm` is the name of the form you want to send messages to.

Comment: If the dll returns any message to myForm, how do I get those value?

Comment: You have to override the method `WndProc` in your form, as exaplained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Please accept my answer if it responds to your question!